# Get records ordered alphabetically starting by a certain letter in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-order-by

In SQLSERVER/MSSQL, here's the problem:

```
SELECT * from [Translation Color] order by [Language Code]
```

I want records ordered in alphabetical order starting by the 'I' letter.

Example of result:

'Ioren'
'Iumen'
'Tart'
'Arfen'
'Coldry'

I don't want to use union or more sql statements.. just try to catch it with an order by special clause.

I've tried with:

```
ORDER BY <field> REGEXP '^I' DESC
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN SUBSTRING([Translation Color],1,1) = 'l' 
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

EDIT:

Full answer for ordering completely starting at i, then looping back round to h is:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING([Translation Color],1,1))) < 73 
         THEN ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING([Translation Color],1,1))) + 26
         ELSE ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING([Translation Color],1,1))) END ASC,       
         [Translation Color] ASC
```

Please note that this will affect performance on large tables.

Comment: Remember to check the performance is acceptable though, especially if you have or are likely to have a large dataset.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, am coding in C# at the mo, but I've edited it to be right.

Comment: BTW - very clever solution - trés bien!

Comment: @Dog Ears: See [== gives error, but with one = it works! thank you – avastreg (49 mins ago)]

Comment: I'm missing the point but don't you want the data to order like this..
l m n o....g h i j k  Does the selected answer do that?

Comment: @Dog Ears, You are correct. The OP suggests that they need the ordering I-ZA-H. ck's answer doesn't deliver this, your answer and mine do. Note though that it's an I (i), not an l (L).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively is this any good:

```
select [Translation Color], 
  case when [Translation Color] < 'l' then 1
                     else 0 
                     end as Priority
from t1 
order by Priority, [Translation Color]
```

This will order it alphabeticly starting at 'l'

**Edit**
This solution seems to work for me:

```
create table t1 ( c1 varchar(20) collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_CI_AS)
```

then i populated with some test data then run this:

```
select c1 
from t1 
order by case when c1 >= 'l' then 0 else 1 end, c1
```

Comment: +1: nice answer, very clean, but does use separate element in select statement

Comment: My edit works perfectly but doesn't uses the order by clause.

Comment: ... *now* uses (not doesn't) the order by clause!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM [Translation Color]
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN [Language Code] LIKE '[I-Zi-z]%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    [Language Code]
```

Comment: +1: Nice answer, but LIKE clause could be quite slow on large data sets, but possible not as  slow as mine :) (however I assume this is a small lookup table)

Comment: @ck, The LIKE isn't ideal, but it should still be able to use any index on the [Language Code] column. I suspect that using SUBSTRING, ASCII, UPPER etc would necessitate a table scan.

Comment: @ck, I agree that it's most likely a small lookup table. However, even if every drop of performance isn't vital, I think that my answer is more readable than all those string functions.

Comment: You answer is indeed more readable.  I like the fact there are three different answers to this question.

Comment: I like this answer as I imagine it's more tolerant of different collations.